# Regular expression to verify a the entered youtube or soundcloud url has correct syntax

Tags: php, regex, laravel-5

I am doing this in laravel php framework. Here is the relevant part that does the validation:

```
$this->validate($request, [
      'portrait_url' => 'required|active_url|regex:https://soundcloud.com/*',
      'video_url' => 'required|active_url|regex:https://www.youtube.com/user/*',
    ]);
```

Unfortunately I get the error that says:

> preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

I think I am not writing my regular expression well. A hint please on the right regex pattern to accomplish my purpose.
Particularly for youtube I want to verify that the entered url is the one that looks like this: `https://www.youtube.com/user/OfficialSinach` the phrase `OfficialSinach` could be replaced by any other username depending on the user being accessed.

Comment: Where's the `preg_match` usage (I dont use larvel)?